# Install MP3 decoder plugin in Fedora

Tags: fedora, mp3, rhythmbox

When I attempt to play a mp3 file Rhythmbox displays the following error:

[image]

How can I install the mentioned plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora doesn't provide mp3-codecs due to some patent-related issues (more details [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Forbidden_items?rd=ForbiddenItems#MP3_Support)). So you should add third-party repository and install codecs from here. E.g you can use [RPM Fusion](http://rpmfusion.org/) and install `gstreamer-plugins-ugly` package.